# How can I exclude rest-auth endpoint from the Django built-in API documentation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-rest-auth

To hide the endpoint in the Django documentation just `@schema(None)` has to be added for example to `GenericAPIView`, however I have a problem with these two urls:

```
url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
```

I am not able to add `@schema(None)` decorator because I do not have declared views for these urls. Any ideas how to work it around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I came up with:

```
(vf, app_name, namespace) = include('rest_auth.urls')

vf.LoginView = schema(None)(vf.LoginView)
vf.LoginView = schema(None)(vf.LogoutView)
vf.LoginView = schema(None)(vf.PasswordChangeView)
vf.LoginView = schema(None)(vf.PasswordResetConfirmView)
vf.LoginView = schema(None)(vf.PasswordResetView)
vf.LoginView = schema(None)(vf.UserDetailsView)

(vf_registration, app_name_registration, namespace_registration) = include('rest_auth.registration.urls')

vf_registration.RegisterView = schema(None)(vf_registration.RegisterView)
vf_registration.TemplateView = schema(None)(vf_registration.TemplateView)
vf_registration.VerifyEmailView = schema(None)(vf_registration.VerifyEmailView)

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^rest-auth/', (vf, app_name, namespace)),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', (vf_registration, app_name_registration, namespace_registration)),
]
```